# Nvidia 304.132 driver update wont boot

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia

My system updated the driver from 304.131 to 304.132.  How do I restore the 131 driver?  The system wont boot under 304 and I had to purge nvidia and use Nouveau.

Nvidia driver is a GeForce9400m.  2009 Macbook 5,2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can and should install the recommended Nvidia driver version (which may or may not be 304) now that you purged the previous version. In order to give you a correct and helpful answer we need to know which Nvidia card you have. Please edit and update with that information.

Comment: Updated.  Its a Geforce 9400m.  Im terrified of using Nouveau.  [If I suspend the machine with Nouveau, it may fail to resume and then boot to a blinking cursor (even grub recovery kernels wont boot) which i cant fix].

Comment: As expected, the only driver version currently recommended by Nividia for your card is **340**. You can check at http://www.geforce.com/drivers . Obs.: Do not install from the site, it's for guidance only. Find it and apply in Additional Drivers.

Comment: Thanks - That driver actually causes a login loop after I install it.  I suspect there is a driver-mismatch going on in the kernel somewhere.  Any suggestions for how to go about installing it?

Comment: That shouldn't be happening if you purged the previous version -> `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`  (the "*" is required). The currently supported releases are 12.04 (ends in a few months), 14.04, 16.04 and 16.10. If any other - End of Life - then that or worse can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reported/Confirmed as Bug #1639180.  I had the same problem and ended up manually installing Nvidia-304.131 (you have to first install the MTRR patch to the Nvidia run file).

Comment: Thanks.  Im commenting as i cannot up-vote your solution.  Here is the link if anyone wants to take a look.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1639180

Comment: Done.  I am using the 340.98 driver as you stated, and things are working.  Not sure why this driver gave me issues in the past but it is working.

Answer (score 0):

This might help without manually installing until nvidia fix this

Downgrade from 304.132 to 304.131:

<kbd>Ctrl+</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> Shift to console

- login
- `sudo apt-get autoremove nvidia*`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-304=304.131-0ubuntu3`

To prevent the broken driver to get reinstalled on the next update, but still get newer updates, you can block it specifically.

Create a file called `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nvidia-bug` with the following content:

```
Explanation: block this specifique update because of OpenGL problem with 304.132
Package: nvidia-304
Pin: version 304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
Pin-Priority: -10

Explanation: block this specifique update because of OpenGL problem with 304.132
Package: nvidia-opencl-icd-304
Pin: version 304.132-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
Pin-Priority: -10
```

The specific version to be blocked depends on your version of Ubuntu. This is for 16.04. Check which version to block by running `apt-cache policy nvidia-304`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I found out that a newer version of nvidia drivers work for me, it seems also your graphics card is supported! Just check the respective nvidia site, which driver version fit for you: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

The run the following commands:

- `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get install nvidia-**driver version**`